# Finder doesn't find duplicates with (1), (2), …, (n) in filename

Tags: macos, finder, search

I have downloaded lots of duplicate files with my web browser. The first duplicate gets the suffix `(1)` in its filename before the file extension, the second gets `(2)` and so on.

For example: `my_music_file(1).mp3`

I'm trying to purge these duplicates by searching for `(1)`, `(2)` and so forth in Finder, but for some reason it does not find the files. Probably because the duplicate suffixes are concatenated with the original file name, without whitespaces before the suffixes.

Can I find these duplicates using a name string search in Finder?
Or indeed by some other OS X native method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) will often find things Spotlight won't - including such as (1)

No affiliation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm happy to take other suggestions to find an appropriate solution. Good that it's freeware.

Comment: Still working fine under 10.11.5 [I just checked their site to see if they're still active, last blog post today, so I assume/hope that they would update it if it needed to be]